# Ruby's ri not working - 'Marshall data too short'

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, ruby

I'm running Lubuntu 13.10, I installed Ruby (1.9.3p194), Gems(1.8.23), ri(4.1.1), rdoc and some gems (Rails, RSpec, haml...) from the apt-get repository. When I try to run ri, it gives me the following message:

```
$ ri Array
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:548:in `load': marshal data too short (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:548:in `block in load_cache'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:547:in `open'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:547:in `load_cache'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:391:in `block in initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:59:in `block in each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:58:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:58:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:385:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:362:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:362:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/bin/ri:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/ri:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/ri:23:in `<main>'hri Array
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:548:in `load': marshal data too short (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:548:in `block in load_cache'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:547:in `open'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/store.rb:547:in `load_cache'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:391:in `block in initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:59:in `block in each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:58:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/paths.rb:58:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:385:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:362:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:362:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/bin/ri:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/ri:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/ri:23:in `<main>'
```

I haven't really found anything useful on Google.

Q: How can I fix this, or how can I correctly install Ruby and the ri Gem on Lubuntu 13.10?